# Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann-integrable functions with values in a Banach space

Tags: integration, banach-spaces

Does anybody know a definition of Riemann-integrability for functions with values in an arbitrary (!) Banach space for which Lebesgue's criterion holds which says that a bounded function is Riemann-integrable if and only if the set of its discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero? For definitions to be found in the literature this is only sufficient but not necessary. Of course, in case the Banach space is just the real numbers this definition should fall back to something which is equivalent to the standard definition. And it is required that this integral retains the standard properties: the Riemann-integrable functions form a vector subspace of the space of all bounded functions and the integral is a linear map from this subspace to the Banach space.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you're going to find a useful/interesting version such that the result holds for every Banach space:

Define $f:[0,1]\to L^\infty([0,1])$ by $$f(t)=\chi_{[t,1]}.$$Then $f$ is nowhere continuous, but it's not hard to show that $$\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt=I,$$where  $$I(t)=t$$(in the strongest reasonable sense, norm convergence of the Riemann sums).

So for the magic definition of integrability *that* function has to be non-integrable. It's such a relatively nice function that it seems likely the definition of the integral can't be all that natural. or useful. Not that this actually proves that, of course...

Comment: Can you do an example using a separable Banach space instead of $L^\infty$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes you convinced me with this example that the set of Riemann.integrable functions would be too small.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know whether "one" can, but I can't, just offhand.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: The Bochner-integral is widely adopted as a "natural" extension of the Lebesgue-integral for real-valued functions to functions with values in an arbitrary Banach space and actually retains the most important properties like the dominated convergence theorem and completeness with respect to the integral-seminorm. The function you have presented is not Bochner-integrable, so would you therefore regard the Bochner-integral as not all that useful?